# C# - IBM WebsphereMQ connection attempt fails with MQRC_HOST_NOT_AVAILABLE (2538)

Tags: c#, ibm-mq

I'm trying to access Websphere through a C# client that I'm working on and getting

> MQRC_HOST_NOT_AVAILABLE / 2538

error.

I have installed WMQ `WS_MQ_FOR_WINDOWS_V8.0` (MQ Server Version 8.0.5 I think) with client-only install option

Referenced `amqmdnet.dll` from `C:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere MQ\bin`

I started by working on a sample code and final version is below:

```
namespace WebsphereMQ
{
    class Program
    {

        const String qManager = "AQMNAME"; //All uppercase
        const String hostName = "ASERVER"; //pinging server name resolves IP successfully. I have also tried using IP which didn't work either
        const String channel = "AQMNAME_CONN"; //All uppercase
        const String port = "1415"; 
        const String sslKeyRepository = @"D:\d\Projects\MyProject\Client\client_4_myapp"; 
        //.kdb file name without extension
        const String cipherSpec = "TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384";
        const String cipherSuite = "SSL_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384";

        public static Hashtable init()
        {
            Hashtable properties = new Hashtable();

            //properties.Add(MQC.TRANSPORT_PROPERTY, MQC.TRANSPORT_MQSERIES_CLIENT);
            properties.Add(MQC.TRANSPORT_PROPERTY, MQC.TRANSPORT_MQSERIES_MANAGED); 
            properties.Add(MQC.HOST_NAME_PROPERTY, hostName);
            properties.Add(MQC.PORT_PROPERTY, port);
            properties.Add(MQC.CHANNEL_PROPERTY, channel);

            properties.Add(MQC.SSL_CERT_STORE_PROPERTY, sslKeyRepository);
            properties.Add(MQC.SSL_CIPHER_SPEC_PROPERTY, cipherSpec);
            properties.Add(MQC.SSL_CIPHER_SUITE_PROPERTY, cipherSuite);



            //properties.Add(MQC.USER_ID_PROPERTY, "someUsername");
            //properties.Add(MQC.PASSWORD_PROPERTY, "somePassword1");


            return properties;
        }

        public static void ConnectToMQ()
        {
            try
            {
                Hashtable connectionProperties = init();
                //Exception is thrown by the line below
                MQQueueManager qMgr = new MQQueueManager(qManager, connectionProperties);

            }
            catch (MQException ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("A WebSphere MQ error occurred: {0}", ex.ToString());
            }
            catch (System.Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("A System error occurred: {0}", ex.ToString());
            }
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ConnectToMQ();
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried CLIENT and MANAGED transport properties with no luck.

Server is up and running.

I can access to the server when I do a Telnet.

No log is generated on server side.

No log is generated on client installdir.

In the eventviewer, I found these:

> 21.02.2017 14:54:57 - Process(4176.1) User(mypcusername) Program(ereMQ.vshost.exe) Host(mypcname) Installation(Installation1)
>   VRMF(8.0.0.0)
>
> Slow DNS lookup for address 'ASERVER'.
>
> An attempt to resolve address 'ASERVER' using the 'getaddrinfo'
>   function call took 7 seconds to complete. This might indicate a
>   problem with the DNS configuration.

And

> 21.02.2017 14:54:57 - Process(4176.1) User(mypcusername) Program(ereMQ.vshost.exe) Host(mypcname) Installation(Installation1)
>   VRMF(8.0.0.0)
>
> Remote host 'ASERVER' not available, retry later.
>
> The attempt to allocate a conversation using TCP/IP to host
>   'ASERVER' for channel AQMNAME_CONN was not successful. However
>   the error may be a transitory one and it may be possible to
>   successfully allocate a TCP/IP conversation later. &P In some cases
>   the remote host  cannot be determined and so is shown as '????'.

Then I changed hostname to IP address again with no luck either. I have also tried omitting `port` property and supplying port info in `hostName`. In that case default port (1414) was being used which didn't work either.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The code looks ok, have you checked to make sure the listener on the Queue Manager is up and running and listening on port 1414? If not maybe a firewall is blocking the connection.

Comment: Application admin confirmed that it's up and running on port 1415. Besides, telnet is also successful which made me think that it's not a firewall issue. Any ideas why no logs are generated on both ends?

Comment: No logs were generated on the server side because nothing reached it. You appear to have error messages written on the client side because you have posted them here. You will also find them in the errors directory in a file called AMQERR01.LOG (for the UNMANAGED CLIENT case at least - I forget where the MANAGED .NET client writes them!). Are you able to run a simple MQ provided sample such as amqscnxc to test connectivity?

Comment: Hi @MoragHughson I couldn't find any log files in either client installdir or my app's debug dir. The logs I provided before are from event viewer sadly. I'm quite new to MQ to be honest. Can you provide a link or sample how to test connectivity?
I wonder if I did something wrong during installation as well. Did a custom install with name Installation1, default path and selected items are MQ Explorer, Windows Client, Java and .Net Messaging and Web Services, Development Toolkit

Comment: Can you look in %MQ_FILE_PATH%\Tools\c\Samples\Bin64 and see if there is a sample called amqscnxc.exe. If there is, run it with the following parameters:-
amqscnxc.exe -x ASERVER(1415) -c AQMNAME_CONN AQMNAME
and report back what happens. If it fails also try with the IP address instead of "ASERVER", and also report the result.

Comment: @MoragHughson First one returned 2538 and second one (with ip) returned 2539.

Comment: Just checked event viewer again and the call with ip says "CCSID supplied for data conversion not supported.  

The program ended because, either the source CCSID '437' or the target CCSID '857' is not valid, or is not currently supported.  "

Comment: So the 2538 (MQRC_HOST_NOT_AVAILABLE) says to me that you are not resolving the hostname ASERVER into an IP address. Are you sure you are specifying the full hostname? I don't know whether you are disguising the value for the purposes of asking your question, but usually there are dots, says machine1.mqgem.com.

When you use the IP address (which *SHOULD* be the same behaviour that you will get if you resolve the hostname succcesfully) you are now onto a different problem. For RC 2539 (MQRC_CHANNEL_CONFIG_ERROR) you should also have an error in the queue manager errorlog. Please provide?

Comment: P.S. Are you using Code Page 857 on your client machine? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_857

Comment: @uTeisT did you find a solution? i'm having the same problem

Comment: Hi @kennydust, actually I did but I no longer have access to the source code as I have left that company. I think in the end I had to use IP address and make some changes on CCSID according to the char-set I needed. I will check again if I still have the source somewhere and will let you know.

Comment: @uTeisT: Could you please add some more info / code sample that how you managed to solve this issue?